# Is it possible to have wide and long form data written to the same CSV in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have two sets of data, one works best in long form and second works best wide form.

Data1:

```
Group   Min.    1st.Qu. Median  Mean    3rd.Qu. Max.
  A     0.04059 0.08226 0.08383 0.1053  0.1367  0.1748
  B     0.03587 0.04283 0.06695 0.06186 0.08141 0.08226
  C     0.05154 0.08919 0.1114  0.1133  0.1449  0.1797
```

data2:

```
 A    B      C
123  454    678
234  42524  678
436  462456 54
345  42562  5645
564  5656   2
```

It would be super cool if I could I could have them like this, human and machine readable.

```
Group   Min.    1st.Qu. Median  Mean    3rd.Qu. Max.     A     B      C
  A     0.04059 0.08226 0.08383 0.1053  0.1367  0.1748   3423  234324 23423
  B     0.03587 0.04283 0.06695 0.06186 0.08141 0.08226  67    3435   34534
  C     0.05154 0.08919 0.1114  0.1133  0.1449  0.1797   4534  3345   34534
                                                         34534 345    3453
                                                               34567  3434
                                                                      657
```

Is this an overly complicated thing to do because of the different numbers of rows?

- edit: To explain the data a little more, the last trailing columns are the data values that the summary statistics are derived from

Comment: You should write two separate CSVs. A CSV [has a well-established standard definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), and what you're asking for doesn't really meet it.

Comment: You could fill in all the spaces with blanks or missing values or something. but it would be very confusing to anyone other than you.

Comment: @Gregor The final product doesn't necessarily need to be a csv or tsv. I'm not clever enough to think of anything else though.

Comment: If you don't need a portable format you should be using `save` and creating an `.rdata` file that can have as many separate R objects in it as you want. `save(data1, data2, file = 'mydata.rdata')`. If that doesn't work, please be clearer about what requirements you *do* have - is the purpose of this to be human or machine readable? For R or for general platforms? Why is one file preferable to two?...

Comment: @Gregor It needs to be portable. It needs to be readable by machine for sure. It needs to be human readable if possible. It is for general platforms.

Comment: So either use 2 files intended for rectangular data - CSV, TSV, feather, etc., or use a single file intended for non-rectangular data, like JSON or XML.